# Python print lines after context

Tags: python, grep, bioinformatics, fasta, fastq

How can I print two lines after the context i am interest in using python.

Example.fastq

```
@read1
AAAGGCTGTACTTCGTTCCAGTTG
+
'(''%$'))%**)2+'.(&&'/5-
@read2
CTGAGTTGAGTTAGTGTTGACTC
+
)(+-0-2145=588..,(1-,12
```

I can find the context of interest using...

```
fastq = open(Example.fastq, "r")

IDs = [read1]

with fastq as fq:
    for line in fq:
        if any(string in line for string in IDs):
```

Now that I have found read1 I want to print out the the following lines for read1.  In bash i might use something like grep -A to do this. The desired output lines look like the following.

```
+
'(''%$'))%**)2+'.(&&'/5-
```

But in python i cant seem to find an equivalent tool.  Perhaps "islice" might work but I don't see how I can get islice to start at the position of the match.

```
with fastq as fq:
    for line in fq:
        if any(string in line for string in IDs):
            print(list(islice(fq,3,4)))
```

Comment: So you have the genetic sequence and you want to know the 2 lines following the sequence in the fastq file are?

Comment: Hey Sam yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to advance an iterator (including files):

```
print(next(fq))
print(next(fq))
```

This consumes those lines, so the `for` loop will continue with `@read2`.

if you don't want the `AAA...` line, you can also just consume it with `next(fq)`. In full:

```
fastq = open(Example.fastq, "r")

IDs = [read1]

with fastq as fq:
    for line in fq:
        if any(string in line for string in IDs):
            next(fq)  # skip AAA line
            print(next(fq).strip())  # strip off the extra newlines
            print(next(fq).strip())
```

which gives

```
+
'(''%$'))%**)2+'.(&&'/5-
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're handling FASTQ files, you're better off using a bioinformatics library like [BioPython](http://biopython.org/) instead of rolling your own parser.

To get the exact result you requested, you can do:

```
from Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO import FastqGeneralIterator

IDs = ['read1']

with open('Example.fastq') as in_handle:
    for title, seq, qual in FastqGeneralIterator(in_handle):
        # The ID is the first word in the title line (after the @ sign):
        if title.split(None, 1)[0] in IDs:
            # Line 3 is always a '+', optionally followed by the same sequence identifier again.
            print('+') 
            print(qual)
```

But you can't do much with the line of quality values on its own. Your next step will be almost certainly be to convert it to [Phred quality scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phred_quality_score). But this is notoriously complicated [because there are at least *three* different and *incompatible* variants of the FASTQ file format](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/0008a0dd3b9f482de15704001bb79623c5baed0a/Bio/SeqIO/QualityIO.py#L69). BioPython takes care of all the edge cases for you, so that you can just do:

```
from Bio.SeqIO import parse

IDs = ['read1']

with open('Example.fastq') as in_handle:
    for record in parse(in_handle, 'fastq'):
        if record.id in IDs:
            print(record.letter_annotations["phred_quality"])
```